# Is there anything after the Puzzle Quest 2 Ending? (Spoilers)

Tags: puzzle-quest-2

I just beat Puzzle Quest 2--at least, I think I did.  I have beaten all side quests (except the repeating 'loot the chest' one), and beaten all main quests.  I got the 'ending' of 'we must remain vigilant' or such.  Is this really all there is to the game?  Am I missing something?  It keeps showing me a main quest trying to send me down to the place where I loot chests--but nothing more.  Am I done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go back and fight everything you left on the way but I think this is the end of the main story. Until the first DLC of course ...